# Hardhat not installing in VSCode on Windows 10

Tags: solidity, hardhat, windows, visual-studio-code

I wanted to install Hardhat in VSCode but it's not installing. I first ran "npm init" then I ran the command "npm install --save-dev hardhat" and I keep getting this error message even though I've switched internet network two times:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/secp256k1/-/secp256k1-4.0.3.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND your-proxy-url
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-19T06_06_48_199Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Consider using my [Hardhat template](https://github.com/paulrberg/hardhat-template).

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your terminal/power shell as administrator privileges. it will solve the error , also make sure better internet connection